# Type mismatch during creation of pivot table : Excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I new to VBA. I am trying to create pivot table for very big record(around 30K Record). This is my code for creating the pivot table. while creating the pivot table it throws error as  "Type mismatch". It was working fine for small set of records.

```
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=rngData, _
Version:=xlPivotTableVersion12).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:=wsPvtTbl.Range("A1"), _
TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion12
```

Please help me on this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Try using a range address rather than a Range object for the `SourceData` argument.

Comment: It worked. But i hardcoded the range now. I need to input dynamically the range based on the input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like this with your rngData variable:

```
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="'" & rngData.Worksheet.name & "'!" & rngData.Address(referencestyle:=xlR1C1), _
Version:=xlPivotTableVersion12).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:=wsPvtTbl.Range("A1"), _
TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion12
```

Comment: It helped me, too, after days spent trying to figure it out!