# VBA returns an error on creating a pivot table

Tags: vba, excel

I am creating a VBA macro. Among other things, it makes a pivot table:

```
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Add(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=Sheets("Working").UsedRange).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="", TableName:="HDPivotTable", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion10
```

This works, but when I delete all data from the Excel spreadsheet and replace it with new data of the same structure, I get an error on the above line:

> Run-time error '13': Type mismatch

How can I fix this?

### Edited

After applying Scott's suggestion, I get another error:

```
With Worksheets("Working")
    lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lColumn = .Range("A" & .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Add(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=.Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lRow, lColumn))).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="", TableName:="HDPivotTable", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion10
End With

ActiveSheet.Name = "HD Pivot"
ActiveSheet.PivotTableWizard TableDestination:=ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1)
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("HDPivotTable").AddFields RowFields:="Location Code"
```

The error is:

> Run-time error '1004': AddFields method of PivotTable class failed

Comment: what if you make `TableName` random/unique each time you run the code?

Comment: @KazimierzJawor You see, I could run the code as many times as needed without problems. The problem started when I replaced the data...

Comment: I found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25870193/type-mismatch-during-creation-of-pivot-table-excel-vba

Answer (score 2):

Most likely what is causing the error is the use of `UsedRange`. While a nifty tool, it also has its drawbacks, especially since you are now replacing data.

For example, if the new data has less columns then the old data, or even less rows, the `UsedRange` will most likely reflect the old range with data. Furthermore, depending upon what you have been doing with your worksheet there may be cells that contain formatting or other characters that you cannot see with the naked-eye, that will affect the `UsedRange`.

If you make the following adjustments in your code, it should work every time.

```
Dim ws as Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Working")

Dim lRow as Long, lColumn as Long

'assumes data table of contiguous rows/columns starting in A1
With ws
    lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlup).Row
    lColumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xltoLeft).Column
End With

ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Add(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=ws.Range(ws.Cells(1,1),ws.Cells(lRow,lColumn)) ...
```

Comment: Thanks, Scott. Please see my addition to the original question.

Comment: @DavidShochet - if this answer correctly solved your initial question, please mark it as answered and create a new question for your new problem (which was not in the original question).

Comment: @DavidShochet - you can mark as answered by clicking the green check mark to the left of the answer.

Comment: I thought it was a part of my original question, as before I changed the data, everything worked. But if you think (or know) that it is a completely new problem, I can add a new question. Please let me know.

Comment: Anyway, I added a new question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35466984/excel-vba-failed-method-on-pivot-table

Comment: @DavidShochet - I considered it a new question because you added additional lines of code than in the original which presented a separate problem. (just so you understand why I said that).

Comment: It seems like this solution only hides the problem. lColumn is 1 in this case, which is not right. But if I use .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column, the lColumn is correct, but the same error about type mismatch occurs again.

Comment: @DavidShochet good catch. I edited the answer appropriately. I just tried playing with your other question a bit more, but ran into issues myself with the rest of the code.