# Excel VBA: Failed method on pivot table

Tags: vba, excel

I am creating a VBA macro. Among other things, it makes a pivot table:

```
With Worksheets("Working")
    lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lColumn = .Range("A" & .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Add(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=.Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lRow, lColumn))).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="", TableName:="HDPivotTable", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion10
End With

ActiveSheet.Name = "HD Pivot"
ActiveSheet.PivotTableWizard TableDestination:=ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1)
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("HDPivotTable").AddFields RowFields:="Location Code"
```

For some reason, I am getting Run-time error '1004': AddFields method of PivotTable class failed

Could you please help?

Question related to this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35461122/vba-error-on-creating-a-pivot-table/35462162#35462162).

Thanks

Comment: are you sure "Location Code" is the name of one of your columns in the new data set? (I also added a link to your previous question - please remove if you think it should not be there, but I think it helps for context).

Comment: @ScottHoltzman "Location Code" is a column in the "Working" worksheet. And I want to add a field with this name to the pivot table. This is said about RowFields parameter: Specifies a field name (or an array of field names) to be added as rows, or to be added to the category axis.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error with your code. Make sure `Location Code` is spelled correctly and has the same amount of space in the middle as inside the source data range for the PT.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Strange, this worked before my previous change was made, i.e. with UsedRange.

Comment: Yes. I did a mini test with the code and a table I created and it worked perfectly.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I noticed that after         lColumn = .Range("A" & .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column, lColumn is 1, which doesn't seem to be right.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman If I replace that line with         lColumn = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column, then lColumn is 47, which is right, but I get the same error as before: Runtime error 13: Type mismatch on ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Add... line.

Comment: David. can you post a screenshot of the actual data set?