# vba pivot cache not created

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

Code below is intended to be a straightforward piot table creation. comment ' ### shows where the error is - basically that the cache does not create so creating the pivot table doesn't happen. I saw a few other users suggest pre-creating the string rather than doing it in-line in the .create statement, but no luck. any help on what the error might be?

```
    ' sht.name is like "Sheet1 Data" so I grab Sheet1 part and add pt or Pivot or ID
Set thisDate = sht.Cells.Find(what:="Date", LookAt:=xlWhole)
sht0 = Split(sht.Name, " ")(0)

Set pvtRg = sht.Range(sht.Cells(thisDate.Row, 1), _
    sht.Cells(sht.UsedRange.Rows.Count, sht.UsedRange.Columns.Count))
pvtRgStr = sht.Range(sht.Cells(thisDate.Row, 1), _
    sht.Cells(sht.UsedRange.Rows.Count, sht.UsedRange.Columns.Count)).Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)


Sheets.Add(after:=sht).Name = sht0 & " Pivot"
Set pvtCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    sht.Name & "!" & pvtRgStr)
' ### persistent 'invalid procedure call here because line above isn't making a pivot cache
Set pvtTable = pvtCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:= _
    sht0 & " Pivot" & "!R3C1", TableName:="pt " & sht0)
    
With Sheets(sht0 & " Pivot").PivotTables("pt " & sht0).PivotFields(sht0 & " ID")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With
Sheets(sht0 & " Pivot").PivotTables("pt " & sht0).AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "pt " & sht0).PivotFields("Impressions"), "Impressions", xlSum
```

Comment: In, `SourceData:= sht.Name & "!" & pvtRgStr`, you need single quotes before and after the sheet name if it has spaces in it - might be a side issue.

Comment: Seems like you can just use a `Range` object for the `TableDestination` too in the following line.

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions for cleaning up:

```
Dim shtNew as worksheet, wb As Workbook
'...
'...
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

Set thisDate = sht.Cells.Find(what:="Date", LookAt:=xlWhole)
sht0 = Split(sht.Name, " ")(0)

' I've never had a problem passing a Range as the source,
'  but see BigBen's comment and link below...
Set pvtRg = sht.Range(sht.Cells(thisDate.Row, 1), _
               sht.Cells(sht.UsedRange.Rows.Count, sht.UsedRange.Columns.Count))
    

Set shtNew = wb.Sheets.Add(after:=sht)
shtNew.Name = sht0 & " Pivot"

Set pvtCache = wb.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
                                     SourceData:= pvtRg)

Set pvtTable = pvtCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:= shtNew.Range("A3"), _
                                         TableName:="pt " & sht0)
    
With pvtTable.PivotFields(sht0 & " ID")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With
pvtTable.AddDataField pvtTable.PivotFields("Impressions"), _
                         "Impressions", xlSum
```

Comment: Isn't it safer to pass `SourceData` a `String`? I feel like I've answered that several times in the past, also based on the docs which mention the possibility of a Type Mismatch otherwise.

Comment: I'm not sure why it would be safer?  These are variant parameters which accept either a Range or a String: I've not seen anything suggesting there's a problem using a Range argument, and creating the string when you already have the Range object seems like one additional step which (if you forget the quotes) can be an issue if your sheet name one day has a space.

Comment: From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivotcaches.create): "When passing a Range object, we recommend that you either use a string to specify the workbook, worksheet, and cell range, or set up a named range and pass the name as a string. Passing a Range object may cause "type mismatch" errors unexpectedly."

Comment: Ok I've never seen/noticed that before: thanks for the heads-up

Comment: There are definitely questions here with `PivotCaches.Create` and a Type Mismatch thrown... One of them has a great answer using `R1C1` notation and passing an address, I just can never find it. I guess Rory has one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25870193/type-mismatch-during-creation-of-pivot-table-excel-vba).

Comment: I see many posts here with problems when the `CreatePivotTable` is directly chained onto the `PivotCaches.Create` - that's how the macro recorder writes it, but splitting them up into two separate calls and using an explicit `PivotCache` object variable for the second part seems to be much more robust.

Comment: I did rotate to string based on comments that I had seen. not sure why it would matter, but I did try that before posting.

Comment: This is almost working now, at least to create the Pivot Cache. Now it errors out on that last data field.                 

.AddDataField pvtTable.PivotFields("Impressions"), "Impressions", xlSum

And I added pvtTable as I think it would be With the wrong thing with just .PivotFields. I tried with and without and got an error both ways. Any help on debugging that last error?

Comment: Try the edit above - sorry I did not test before posting.